# How do I create and use a Form helper in a plugin?

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I'm trying to extend the FormHelper to include some custom controls. I want to do this as part of a plugin. The documentation is a bit sketchy on how to achieve this.

I've created the desired helper in the following folder structure:

```
\plugins\MyPlugin\src\View\Helper\MyFormHelper
```

The helper looks like this:

```
<?php

use Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper as BaseFormHelper;

class MyFormHelper extends BaseFormHelper
{
}
```

... yes it's empty for now. The docs on plugins is a bit vague but it seems to say that one can load this helper in the following way within the main application's `AppView.php::initialise()` method:

```
$this->loadHelper('MyPlugin.MyFormHelper');
```

However this doesn't work. Doing it this way I get a FATAL error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class MyFormHelper, because the name is already in use in /Users/geoidesic/MyApp/plugins/MyPlugin/src/View/Helper/MyFormHelper.php on line 12
```

The question is then how to make use of this plugin helper?  Specifically I'd like to override the default FormHelper for the app. There is a `className` option for `loadHelper` but I can't find a way to make that work with the plugin helper either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the namespace for the helper. Should be like this:

```
<?php

  namespace MyPlugin\View\Helper
  use Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper as BaseFormHelper;

  class MyFormHelper extends BaseFormHelper
  {
  }
```